# getting error, Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, where-clause

What needs to be changed in the below queries?. i want all those employees whose date_of_leaving is null or the date_of_leaving is in between the past 60 days or the date_of_leaving is greater than or equal to the Date.today or current date.

```
employees = @company.employees.where('date_of_leaving BETWEEN ? AND ? OR date_of_leaving IS NULL OR date_of_leaving IS >= Date.today', Date.today - 60, Date.today)
```

i tried in another way also like below.

```
employees = Company.find(4).employees.where('date_of_leaving BETWEEN ? AND ? OR date_of_leaving IS NULL OR date_of_leaving IS >= ?', Date.today - 60, Date.today,Date.today)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the phrase `IS >=` .

You shouldn't use `is` with comparison operators.  Just the operator.  Take out that and it looks good otherwise.